# ARKit – Detect similar objects but with different colours

Tags: iphone, machine-learning, augmented-reality, arkit

Im using [Apple ARKit Scanner](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects) app to scan objects and then detect those objects. I'm wondering is it possible to scan two identical objects but of different colours and be able to detect the difference.

I suspect the scanner generates reference points on the object which are then detected but is there a way to get it to pick up colour difference?

Example would be two trainers of the same style but one black and one white.

I'm thinking maybe an ARReferenceImage may be a better option as I don't really need all round detection from different angles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ML-algorithm of ARKit detects a pre-scanned objects (in `.arobject` container) in black-and-white scheme, not in RGB colour scheme. If you scan two absolutely similar volumetric objects but with a different colour scheme, there's no any guarantee ARKit will recognise each of them successfully.

[image]